# WireGuard IPv6 profile works with wg-quick but not NetworkManager

Tags: networkmanager

I am currently using WireGuard using `wg-quick` and everything works. It uses a manually defined IPv6 address, but no IPv4 address.

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=
Address = xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/128
DNS = 1.1.1.1
MTU = 1280
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
AllowedIPs = ::/0
Endpoint = wg.example.com:xxxx
```

```
7: xxxx0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet6 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I tried to use `NetworkManager` instead of `wg-quick`. After importing it, `nmcli conn import type wireguard file xxxx0.conf`, the interface does not work any more and is stuck with `0 B received`, or at least with this particular server.

A generated address is added to the interface, in addition to setting up the original IPv6 address.

```
10: xxxx0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet6 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/128 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I think removing this additional IPv6 address should fix the issue. How do I prevent this additional IPv6 address from being used or added, so that only the manually specified one is used? I tried looking for options with `nmcli conn show xxxx0`, but I could not find anything obvious.

I don't know what else could be different between `NetworkManager` and `wg-quick`. I tried comparing `ip rule` and `ip route show table <from rule>`, but those were basically the same for both.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/eNV25/b6686966e70c42836b25841bb1a994ca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link noprefixroute

that's a link local address. That's unlikely the cause for the problem.

You said you compared what NetworkManager configured. It would see, that a potential difference can be clearly seen there.

Check `wg show`, `ip addr`, `ip -4 route show table all`, `ip -6 route show table all`, `ip -4 rule`, `ip -6 rule`.

In particular, you don't have an IPv4 address configured -- despite setting `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` and `DNS = 1.1.1.1`. Due to `AllowedIPs` and `wireguard.ip4-auto-default-route` setting, NetworkManager will add a default route for IPv4 (in a different routing table). That route will lead nowhere.

I don't think that IPv4 is going to work via the VPN. Did you check whether IPv6 works?

Fix your configuration, to either configure an IPv4 address or don't add an endpoint range for 0.0.0.0/0. Or at least, disable `wireguard.ip4-auto-default-route`, then NetworkManager won't automatically add the nonsensical default route -- not sure why that would be useful though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but I gave up trying to fix the issue. I might try again later.